Can you use 晩ご飯 as a time indicator?
So, after some years I'm back to the process of studying Japanese. I've come across the following sentence:


晩ご飯はレストランで食べました。


Although the meaning is clear, upon reading I was perplexed about the construction of the sentence. Had it been an adverb of time like 今日 instead of 晩ご飯, the usage with the は particle would make sense to me, as it would put emphasis on it, marking the time as the topic. So, is 晩ご飯 used as an adverb of time above? If I were to formulate the sentence, I would say


レストランで晩ご飯を食べました。


So that 晩ご飯 is the rightful object of 食べる. If 晩ご飯 above has the role of an adverb of time, the difference between 1 and 2 should be a nuance (similarly to this old question of mine), depending on what I want to stress. Is that correct?
So, summarizing: why can we write sentence 1 with 晩ご飯 and is there any reason to prefer 1 to 2?

は is a topic marker, not a time marker. In Sentence 1, 晩ご飯 is marked with は, and this means 晩ご飯 is the topic of the sentence. And this simply means the sentence is about the speaker's dinner. In other words, the speaker wants to say something about their dinner. So it's like this:

晩ご飯はレストランで食べました。
As for my dinner, I ate it at a restaurant.

Note that 晩ご飯 is also the object of 食べる, but since it has been topicalized, it's marked with は instead of を.
See also: What is a topic prominent language?

Yes, I know it is a topic marker. What I didn't know is that you could use topic markers like that. Your example "As per my dinner" explains it perfectly. I thought that the topic still had to have a more direct role in the sentence, as it often happens when the topic is the subject or an indicator of time. Anyways, your example really made things clear.

@Mr.Feynman In modern Japanese, は follows some case particles (e.g. には, では), but replaces が and を, however archaically を + は → をば.
